# Query list of dictionary C# Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to query a list of dictionary by dictionary key and value using linq. The following gives me the error of "cannot convert keyvaluepair to type bool."
Thanks in advance.

```
    var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    foreach (DataRow row in wordCloud.Rows)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in wordCloud.Columns)
        {
            dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];

        }


    list.Add(dict);

    }


    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        var item = list.Where(dict => dict.Where(x => x.Key == "word" && x.Value == text)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Thanks this is what I am using.

```
var item = list.Where(dict => dict["WORD"].Equals(text)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: .Where needs a expression that can be evaluated to bool value. Try using list.Select

Comment: `dict.Where(x => x.Key == "word" && x.Value == text)` returns a collection of keyvaluepairs from the dictionary. So you're asking for "Give me items from the list where a collection of dictionary entries." Doesn't make sense in English either.

Comment: `dict.Where(x => x.Key == "word" && x.Value == text)` -- This is completely using a dictionary the wrong way. There will be no more than one item in the dictionary with that key. Do not loop over it, go right to it. If you're unsure the item with that key exists, check it first with ContainsKey. Do not force yourself to use Linq where it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: Wrong approach! You have to use single `Dictionary` instead of list of them. Then you'll ba able to use `Dictionary`'s methods and properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler error is caused by your predicate in `list.Where` not using a Boolean expression. `dict.Where(...)` is going to produce an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`, which is not a Boolean operation. Furthermore, your technique misuses a dictionary, because it will only have one pair that has a given key, there is no need to loop over it. To deal with both issues, I suggest writing a method to investigate the dictionary and produce a Boolean result for matches.

```
bool DictionaryContainsText(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string text)
{
    string key = "word";
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key) && dictionary[key] != null)
    {
        return dictionary[key].Equals(text);
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then consume this method in the filtering of your list.

```
var item = list.Where(dict => DictionaryContainsText(dict, text)).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

All that said, I wonder if you are starting from the wrong design? A `DataTable` to a `List<Dictionary<K,V>>` seems a bit less intuitive to use than a list of a defined type. Should you not consider defining a class with appropriately named (and typed!) properties that you could consume instead? This is left as an activity for you to consider.

Comment: Why to force such of solution? Please, read my comment to the question.

Comment: @MaciejLos, he is reading multiple rows and is using column names as the keys. He cannot use a single dictionary for this (multiple rows, multiple uses of the same key). My question to the asker is different, I am not sure he should be using a dictionary *at all.*

Comment: I saw your comment and i need to say that is very good question!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is happening because the predicate of `list.Where( ... )` is `dict => dict.Where( ... )` which isn't a Boolean value.

Depending on how you want your code to work, you could potentially replace it with `list.FirstOrDefault(dict => dict.Any( ... ))`, which would eventually return the first dictionary that contains the key-value pair ("word", text). (I think this is the intended functionality of the code, but I can't be positive without further information.)